# MSMQ really slow performance with Recoverable=true

Tags: performance, msmq, persistent

The performance of my Microsoft message queue (MSMQ) is at least a factor ten slower, if I enable persistent messages, by setting the [Recoverable attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.message.recoverable.aspx) to true. I did expect a drop in performance, since the messages are written to disk instead of being stored in memory, but nowhere nearly by that much.

Can I make some performance tuning of my message queue?

Edit: My messages are about 2 kilobytes each. With an in-memory version I can create about 10 messages per second. With message stored on disk, the speed is about 1 per second.

I completede agree, that performance penalty is expected, but I think that 10 messages per second is already so slow, that I thought that it was the sevice writing the messages, that was the bottleneck.

Comment: I'm impressed that it's only a factor of ten slower, given the difference in access times between memory and disk.

Comment: How big are your messages? What are the rates before and after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-recoverable messages still get written to disk but MSMQ doesn't wait for confirmation of success.["Why are my Express MSMQ messages being written to disk?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/04/04/why-are-my-express-messages-being-written-to-disk.aspx)

10 Express messages per second is incredibly slow, as is one Recoverable message per second. There is something seriously wrong with the machine you are using, or the service.
On my desktop machine, I can send 1,000 Recoverable 2kb messages in 6-7 seconds.

Cheers
John Breakwell